# Microsoft Azure - Performance Test always end up with failed/exceptions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance-testing, load-testing, azure-web-app-service

A web site builds with .NET 4.7 along with a Web API 2.0 is deployed to Azure Paas. Its working fine for 100 user load simultaneously.

Web Performance and Load Test

When running the performance test from Azure or Visual Studio, the result is like Exceptions and failures. The exception subtype is SocketException and the Last Message is "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote server". See the attached screenshot for more detail.

The same things happened with LoadTest perform from Visual Studio or VSTS through Http Archive.

We need to pass this as per client requirements.

App Service Settings images are also attached.
[image]

Also, try with Https Only ON, and TLS version 1.2.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are at the maximum threshold capability of the web server. You mentioned you get error when the number of virtual users exceeded 100. It's very possible that the web server doesn't have enough resource to handle requests, so some requests are time out.

Please check the CPU usage, available memory and other counters to determine if the web server has enough resource to handle requests at a high user load.

Hope it helps

Comment: Well, as I mentioned the problem is with even 1 virtual user(Load or performance test). CPU, memory and other infrastructure are in a healthy state.